# Is there way to embed non-tf functions to a tf.Keras model graph as SavedModel Signature?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to add preprocessing functions and methods to the model graph as a SavedModel signature.

example:

```py
# suppose we have a keras model
# ...

# defining the function I want to add to the model graph
@tf.function
def process(model, img_path):
    # do some preprocessing using different libs. and modules...

    outputs = {"preds": model.predict(preprocessed_img)}
    return outputs

# saving the model with a custom signature
tf.saved_model.save(new_model, dst_path, 
                    signatures={"process": process})
```

or we can use `tf.Module` here. However, the problem is I can not embed custom functions into the saved model graph.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you slightly misunderstand the purpose of `save_model` method in Tensorflow.

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) the intent is to have a method which serialises the model's graph so that it can be [loaded](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) with `load_model` afterwards.

The model returned by `load_model` is a class of `tf.Module` with all it's methods and attributes. Instead you want to serialise the prediction pipeline.

To be honest, I'm not aware of a good way to do that, however what you can do is to use a different method for serialisation of your preprocessing parameters, for example [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or a different one, provided by the framework you use and write a class on top of that, which would do the following:

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, model_path, preprocessing_path):
        self.model = load_model(model_path)
        self.preprocessing = load_preprocessing(preprocessing_path)

    def predict(self, img_path):
        return self.model.predict(self.preprocessing(img_path))
```

Comment: thanks for answering the question. I think you are right, it is better to choose a different approach. By the way, your example was so helpful.